# Create a new column using a map

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way (not using a UDF) to take an existing dataframe and create a new column by taking an existing column and pulling out it's equivalent value from a map?

```
df.withColumn("newCol", transform(col("existing").using(map)))
```

where `map`'s key type is the same as the `existing`, with the value being the output I want.

Comment: You can map over the Dataframe and emit a new Row with the added field but what's wrong with a UDF?

Comment: It's my own restriction...it's for a training class and this is just going to glaze over this area due to timing...so I won't have time for explaining udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `Map` to a `DataFrame` and `join`:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), (3, "foobar")
)).toDF("id", "existing")

val map = Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2)
val lookup = sc.parallelize(map.toSeq).toDF("key", "value")

df
 .join(lookup, $"existing" <=> $"key", "left")
 .drop("key")
 .withColumnRenamed("value", "newCol")
```

Comment: Yah....I had thought about that, but was hoping there might be something more elegant than a join. I was also hoping to keep the map external as this is going to be for teaching and wanted to exhibit broadcast variables.

Comment: If you want to use a broadcast variable the only option that comes to mind is an UDF.  Something like `udf((x: T)  => map.value.get(x))` shouldn't require much explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqtx.implicits._
val x = Map("foo" -> 1,"bar"-> 2, "baz"->3)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), (3, "foobar")
)).toDF("id", "existing")
df.map(r => (r.getInt(0),x.getOrElse(r.getString(1),0))).toDF("id","new")
```